# Array of doubles

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I fix this code to fill an Array x with doubles from `1.0`  to `15.0`?

```
int temp = 15;

string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < temp; j++)
    {
        x.Add[i][j]((double) j);
    }       
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can change the type of j to double in order to avoid having to cast it to a double.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Array x".  x is a list currently.  Do you mean you want to fill each of x[0] through x[3] each with an array containing 1.0 to 15.0?

Comment: small remark: you run your for loop from 0..14, and the values you want to insert are j+1, not j

Comment: @mydogisbox You don't really have to cast anything.

Comment: @NullUserException good point.  I always mix up when casting is actually needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answer to my question above is "yes" then here is an answer:

```
        int temp = 15;

        string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
        List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
        {
            double[] test = new double[15];
            for (int j = 1; j <= temp; j++)
            {
                test[j-1] = j;
            }
            x.Add(test);
        }
```

Comment: this code fills test with 0..14. you need to change to `test[j] = j + 1;`

Comment: No. now `test[0]` is equal to `0`. You need `for (int j = 0; j < temp; j++) test[j] = j +1;`

Comment: @Reniuz yeah, I forgot the -1

Answer (score 1):

```
int temp = 15;

string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
{
    double[] y = new double[temp];

    for (int j = 0; j < temp; j++)
    {
        y[j] = j + 1;
    }

    x.Add(y);
}
```

As a note, `x` could be an `Array`.

Or perhaps you don't really need a `List` of `Array`s of `double`. You could simply use a jagged array of `double[]`.

```
int temp = 15;

string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
double[][] x = new double[titles.Length][];

for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
{
    double[] y = new double[temp];

    for (int j = 0; j < temp; j++)
    {
        y[j] = j + 1;
    }

    x[i] = y;
}
```

Comment: I think its better to modify the array before putting it into the other array, otherwise you're modifying something that you've already handed off to something else.

Comment: @mydogisbox At least you don't forget to copy it somewhere else! It's quite common to "lose" the single row when it's near the big `for`